# ReSharper cannot resolve collection type in comments

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper has trouble resolving a name of the collection if it appears in a method description, referenced by `cref` attributed.

For instance in this signature ReSharper underlines the word `Dictionary`:

```
/// <summary>
/// The reconstruct in single account.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="programId">
/// The program id.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="Dictionary"/>.   // <-- here the "Dictionary" is underlined
/// </returns>
Dictionary<long, Account> ReconstructInSingleAccount(long programId)
{

}
```

When I hover over highlighted area it says `Cannot resolve symbol 'Dictionary'`. The file has a reference to `System.Collections.Generic`. The same happens for `IEnumerable` and for `List`.

It doesn't have any influence on code, doesn't prevent compiling or anything. Still I prefer to keep my files cleaned and I don't think ReSharper should have problems resolving names in comments in the first place.

I'm using ReSharper 8.0. Any suggestion how to fix this or how to change my comments to get rid of this "unresolved" warning highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a particular syntax within an XML comment for referring to generics:

```
/// The <see cref="Dictionary{TKey,TValue}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Funny thing is that I generate comments using ReSharper so I'd expect it should generate it in a correct form.

Comment: Exactly what steps did you take that made it generate the _wrong_ form?

Comment: I selected "Insert header" option from the menu ReSharper opens when you select the yellow lgith bulb

Comment: Hmmm... I've never seen that. Exactly what did you click? Do you know what settings you set to get that? Do you have a ReSharper plug-in installed?

Comment: It's on my work machine. I'll return to you with more details on Monday.